# pycuda cannot find the kernel cuModuleGetFunction failed: named symbol not found

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I have the following script that tries to paint a rectangle on a image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule


def draw_square(image_gpu, image_width,image_height, x, y, width, height, color):
    block_dim = (16, 16)  # CUDA block dimensions
    grid_dim_x = (image_width + block_dim[0] - 1) // block_dim[0]  # CUDA grid dimensions (x-axis)
    grid_dim_y = (image_height + block_dim[1] - 1) // block_dim[1]  # CUDA grid dimensions (y-axis)

    mod = SourceModule("""
        __global__ void draw_square_kernel(unsigned char *image, int image_width, int x, int y, int width, int height, unsigned char *color)
        {
            int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
            int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            
            if (row >= y && row < y + height && col >= x && col < x + width)
            {
                int pixel_idx = row * image_width * 3 + col * 3;
                image[pixel_idx] = color[0];
                image[pixel_idx + 1] = color[1];
                image[pixel_idx + 2] = color[2];
            }
        }
    """, no_extern_c=True)

    draw_square_kernel = mod.get_function("draw_square_kernel")
    draw_square_kernel(image_gpu, np.int32(image_width), np.int32(x), np.int32(y),
                       np.int32(width), np.int32(height), cuda.In(color, block=block_dim, grid=(grid_dim_x, grid_dim_y)))


# Load the image
image_path = 'Lena.png'  # Replace with the path to your image
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert the image to the RGB format
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Upload the image to the GPU
image_gpu = cuda.to_device(image_rgb)

# Define the square coordinates
x, y = 100, 100  # Top-left corner coordinates
width, height = 200, 200  # Width and height of the square

# Define the color of the square (Green in this example)
color = np.array([0, 255, 0], dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw a square on the GPU image
draw_square(image_gpu, image_rgb.shape[1], image_rgb.shape[0],x, y, width, height, color)

# Download the modified image from the GPU
image_with_square = np.empty_like(image_rgb)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(image_with_square, image_gpu)

# Convert the image back to the BGR format for display
image_with_square_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(image_with_square, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Display the image with the square
cv2.imshow('Image with Square', image_with_square_bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However when I try to run it I get

```
     python 3_rectangle6.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cbe421fe-1303-4821-9392-a849bfdd00e2/MyStudy/PyCuda/practice/3_rectangle_pycuda3.py", line 52, in <module>
    draw_square(image_gpu, image_rgb.shape[1], image_rgb.shape[0],x, y, width, height, color)
  File "/cbe421fe-1303-4821-9392-a849bfdd00e2/MyStudy/PyCuda/practice/3_rectangle_pycuda3.py", line 29, in draw_square
    draw_square_kernel = mod.get_function("draw_square_kernel")
  File "/miniconda3/envs/py39Cuda2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycuda/compiler.py", line 332, in get_function
    return self.module.get_function(name)
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuModuleGetFunction failed: named symbol not found
```

As you can see this is my sixth attempt, and still draw_square_kernel is not recognized...

Comment: If you ask for C++ linkage, you must load the mangled symbol name

Comment: I am sorry, what exactly? I am learning how to use pycuda, and yes I can see the kernel is C++ but I don't see where the linkage goes or what symbol name

Comment: You are specifying `no_extern_c=True`. The PyCUDA documentation explains what that means and if you care to Google for "C++ symbol mangling" all will become apparent

Answer (score 1):

Because you have added the `no_extern_c=True` option to your SourceModule instance, the code you pass to the compiler is not automagically bracketed with `extern "C" {}` and the resulting compilation is made using C++ rather than C linkage.
CUDA uses the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling), so the resulting mangled symbol name will be something like:

`_Z18draw_square_kernelPhiiiiiS_`.

To get your code to work, you can either remove the `no_extern_c=True` option (but take the time to understand what the implications of that are), or use the mangled symbol name in the `get_function` call. You can nvcc or an object analysis tool to get the exact mangled symbol name for your kernel.